# How to completely backup every single piece of data on samsung s9

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I want to do a full backup of my phone but backing up via the cloud doesn't backup everything and backing up via sd card doesn't backup everything either. If you tried to backup via any of these options, the screen will give you a small link containing the things that it won't backup. However, the items excluded from backup are different. Do you think if I tried to backup via both options it will cover everything on my phone? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: What you want may be impossible depending on your used apps. If an app uses the Android keystone the keys are bound to your CPU and can't be extracted from the device even on a rooted device. Furthermore apps can disallow backup that makes backup again impossible (can be bypassed on rooted devices).

Comment: that is always the hen-egg-dilemma when it comes to rooting. try samsung kies or samsung smart switch